# Override child route in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In an angular2 child module I define some fairly generic routes:

MyChildModule:

```
const childRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: "daten/:entityname/add", component: DatenAddRowComponent },
    { path: "daten/:entityname/:id", component: DatenEditRowComponent },
    { path: "daten/:entityname", component: DatenRowsComponent },
    { path: "daten", component: DatenEntitiesComponent },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(childRoutes)
    ],
    // ...
})
```

In my AppModule itself I want to override some of these routes:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: "daten/User/add", component: UserAddComponent },
    // ...
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
        MyChildModule
    // ...
```

Problem is: When I visit `/daten/User/add` it will use the child route `daten/:entityname/add` instead of the main app-route. The child route has precedence. `UserAddComponent` is never invoked.

How can I override a child route in the main AppModule?

Comment: Do you think maybe implementing CanActivateChild in a guard would do the trick? Seems a bit like a hassle.

Comment: my full code has AuthGuards, but I got no idea how to implement a child guard. Especially since different main apps might override different routes from the module.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the order as below

```
const childRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: "daten", component: DatenEntitiesComponent ,'pathMatch' :'full' },
    { path: "daten/:entityname/add", component: DatenAddRowComponent },
    { path: "daten/:entityname/:id", component: DatenEditRowComponent },
    { path: "daten/:entityname", component: DatenRowsComponent },

];
```

and in your main app

```
 { path: "daten/User/add", component: UserAddComponentm 'pathMatch' :'full' },
```

Comment: I think it will work let me know if u need more help

Comment: Nope, when I visit `/daten/User/add` it will still use the child route `daten/:entityname/add` instead of the main app-route. The child route has precedence.

Comment: did u try this?

Comment: Yep, I changed the code and it will still visit the child route - even though I don't really understand why your changes would change the routing precedence. Can you explain the reasoning?

Comment: try adding pathMatch as full to all the routes in the **childRoutes** variable. We shall fix it first and then I will explain

Comment: Added pathMatch:'full' to all child routes, did not help. Still I would not understand why it could help, since `daten/:entityname/add` is a full match to `daten/User/add`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138418/discussion-between-aravind-and-sam).